# AWKing or GREPing brackets [ ]?

Tags: awk, grep

I've searched all over and couldn't find a solution.

How would I awk or grep the following:

```
$ mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --query-ip-configuration
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] IPv4 configuration available: 'address, gateway, dns'
 IP [0]: '11.22.333.44/55'
Gateway: '14.13.198.4'
DNS [0]: '172.17.1.101'
DNS [1]: '172.17.1.102'
DNS [2]: '172.17.1.101'
DNS [3]: '172.17.1.102'
```

So that I end up with:

```
11.22.33.44/55
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations with both grep and awk and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cat file` as I don't have `mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --query-ip-configuration`:

```
$ cat file | awk -F"'" '/IP \[/{print $2}'
11.22.333.44/55

$ cat file | awk -F"'" '/Gateway/{print $2}'
14.13.198.4
```

or maybe this is all you need if the output of that command always looks like the example you posted:

```
$ cat file | awk -v RS= -F"'" '{print $5}'
11.22.333.44/55

$ cat file | awk -v RS= -F"'" '{print $8}'
14.13.198.4
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, I didn't realize there were a bunch of commands to achieve the same result, but I tested your methods and they work perfectly.  I think its the cleanest of the options too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single `awk`:

```sh
mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --query-ip-configuration |
awk '$1 == "IP" {gsub(/\047/, "", $NF); print $NF}'

11.22.333.44/55
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.  Could I use something similar to grab the IP address from the second line Gateway: '14.13.198.4'??

Comment: Almost.. the Gateway: '14.13.198.4' line does not have the same [0] that the IP line has, ie "IP [0]:"... so I'd need to figure out how to adjust accordingly.

Comment: You can use: `awk '$1 == "Gateway:" {gsub(/\047/, "", $NF); print $NF}'`

Comment: @DonTSpamme: Did my suggested awk work for you?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
grep '[0-9]' file_with_text | awk '{print $NF}
```

grep `[0-9]` only lines with numbers and pipe the output into awk.
The `$NF` will return the last element.
If you want only the line that has the `/`, just add it to grep `[0-9]/`.

Also, for a complete answer, you can pipe the output of the command into grep:

```
mbimcli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --query-ip-configuration | grep '[0-9]/' | awk '{print $NF}
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you!  One more question, is there a way to eliminate the ' ' encasing the returned IP address? I'm getting '11.22.33.44/55' and need 11.22.33.44/55 to store it in a env variable and the quotes will get in the way down the road.

Comment: use sed the replace the `'` with nothing `| sed "s/'//g"` (please accept the answer and vote up if it helped you:) )

Comment: You never need grep or sed when you're using awk. For example, `grep '[0-9]/' | awk '{print $NF}' | sed "s/'//g"` = `awk '/[0-9]\//{gsub(/\047/,""); print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

I would harness `tr` for preprocessing and GNU `AWK` for processing, let `file.txt` content be

```
 IP [0]: '11.22.333.44/55'
Gateway: '14.13.198.4'
DNS [0]: '172.17.1.101'
DNS [1]: '172.17.1.102'
DNS [2]: '172.17.1.101'
DNS [3]: '172.17.1.102'
```

then

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "'" | awk '/IP/{print $NF}'
```

output

```
11.22.333.44/55
```

Explanation: use `tr` to delete `'` then `awk` to print last column (`$NF`) if row contain `IP`.

*(tested in tr (GNU coreutils) 8.30 and GNU Awk 5.0.1)*